# variable height list items in a div, align bottom

Tags: html, css

can we take this existing fiddle (solution) for a bar chart and apply different height values,

http://jsfiddle.net/RYBFF/1/

what actually happening is the bar items are anchored to top of ul container whereas it should be anchored to the bottom when we scale items.

```
li.different {
    height: 80px !important;
}
```

for instance applying different class to one of the list items will demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change display mode to `inline-block`
- remove `float: left;`

And eventually add some margin to the first item in the list.

`vertical-align` only applies to inline or inline-block elements. Your list items were block elements.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRJwx)

Comment: cool, I like that, can you please explain me a bit so I can understand technically. Thanks.

Comment: yeah I understand now after your edit about the vertical-align, question if we had block elements, how do we anchor them to bottom?

Comment: Using absolute positioning and the `bottom` property, like you did with the `<ul>`. Also note that once you float an element, it will automatically turn into a block element.

Comment: awesome, you know this stuff is not in the books, or can you recommend me any that goes into this kind of complicated css structures, I mean i read a lot and they teach structuring headers, footers, float left/right etc. I want to learn more than this. Please advise.

Comment: Well, I learned it just by experimenting. And when something is unclear, I turn to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or Stackoverflow. You're doing that too, so you're on the right track I guess :)